# MVC4 mobile Web app into app store

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed an web app using MVC4- mobile and HTML5. Every things is working fine when we enter URL from any phone. But i am wondering how to convert my web app into hybrid app so that i could upload in istore or GooglePlay.

Please help me with the procedure or steps i need to follow and is there any tool other than phoneGap that i could use.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few options but I will mention only two of them.

1. Most commonly used is a Phonegap/Cordova app wrapper framework (Also my main choice). Cordova is a new name for a Phonegap framework. It will give you an access to common mobile phone functionalities (Android, iPhone, Blackberry and WP7+). It is rather easy to use and there are a lot of vorking tutorials available, you can even find them in youtube.

   Here's an phonegap link: http://cordova.apache.org/. There you will find tutorials how to install/configure it on all available platforms. This is a older link: [enter link description here](http://phonegap.com/), it still has usable informations.

   If in doubt always search for phonegap examples instead of cordova. For some reason Phonegap is still a mostly used name.

   Here's an Phonegap + jQuery Mobile example: http://therockncoder.blogspot.com/2012/07/jquery-mobile-phonegap-and-camera.html, there you will find a github link for Android and iOS implementation.

   ***Through the PhoneGap javascript APIs***, the "web app" has access to the mobile phone functions such as Geolocation, Accelerometer Camera, Contacts, Database, File system, etc. Basically any function that the mobile phone SDK provides can be "bridged" to the javascript world. On the other hand, a normal web app that runs on the mobile web browser does not have access to most of these functions (security being the primary reason). Therefore, a PhoneGap app is more of a mobile app than a web app. You can certainly use PhoneGap to wrap a web app that does not use any PhoneGap APIs at all, but that is not what PhoneGap was created for.

   Now some ***disadvantages***. With PhoneGap for each platform you have to maintain a different project. The burden for that increases when there is a need to use multiple PhoneGap plugins because you need to search and update different files on each platform.
2. Mosync is also an excellent solution. This framework has a few things better handled then Phonegap. Like:

   - With MoSync you’ll have only one project to maintain for all the platforms. For iOS you will still need to use Xcode because MoSync outputs a project for it but, other than just building it, there is no need to dig deeper in Apple’s IDE.
   - The entire provided functionality for JavaScript is placed in the same file for all of the operating systems. There are no files for plugins because it has none (at least that I know of), but the same extensibility is achieved in ways described in the next section.
   - If there is some functionality that MoSync doesn’t provide on the JavaScript side, there are no plugins that you can use, but there is another way. MoSync provides a lot of features from the C++ side and if they aren’t accessible from JavaScript by default they can be easily made available. I’m sure that in the future the MoSync team will add more features to the JavaScript library.
   - With MoSync you are not restricted to only JavaScript frameworks to replicate native UI, you can truly create native UI elements that are more responsive using only JavaScript.
3. Rhomobile on the other hand is much less used thus a lot less supported.

   I heard few good things about this framework but never had time to learn/use it.

> RhoMobile applications are OS-agnostic, able to support enterprise-
>   and consumer-class operating systems including Windows® Embedded
>   Handheld, Windows® CE, Windows® Phone 7 Series, Apple® iOS, Android®
>   and BlackBerry®. You have complete control over how applications
>   behave on different devices. With RhoMobile Suite, you are finally
>   free from OS design constraints, able to create business applications
>   that are every bit as elegant looking and intuitive as their consumer
>   counterparts (This was copied from their main site).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Currently i am using php code and connect to database to dynamically create the page. So if i use a phone gap, i guess i wont be able to connect with the database. My target is to create a iphone app from windows machine and use dynamic content. Will it be possible?? please guide me...  should i create a service and load every thing jquery? or is there any other way to do it..

Comment: This example solved the issue: https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS